# RewriteRule wildcard subdomain keep url

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my Wordpress instance each user has a public profile, and I'm trying to make a dynamic URL rewriting allowing a user profile to be accessed with his nickname as subdomain.

For example : 
`username.example.com` should display the page `example.com/membres/username/profile`

`username.example.com/foo` should display the page `example.com/membres/username/profile/foo`

The `www` subdomain is an exception and should redirect to main domain.
Also, I need to use https.

I added `*.example.com` in the virtual host and DNS and got a letsencrypt wildcard certificate.

Here is what I got at this moment in my .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# www subdomain exception
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com [L,R=301]

# profile redirection
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([\w\d]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/membres/%1/profile/$1 [L,NC]
```

The redirection is behaving exactly how I need. SSL is good too.

foo.mysite.com is sending me to https/example.com/membres/foo/profile

But I can't find the right way to keep the URL like `foo.example.com`!

I tried some examples using the `[P]` flag, but at this point I don't know what I'm doing.

How can I prevent this ?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the external url redirection,You need to remove the `scheme` (https:://) and hostname from your destination url.

```
# profile redirection
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([\w\d]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/membres [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /membres/%1/profile/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: This is giving me a 500 internal error... In apache log it says "AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error"

Comment: @FLX yes the request was looping due to un conditional rewriting.  I added a condition to prevent that.

Comment: Still Error 500, but your solution should work to me, I don't see any flaw :/ Do you think I could be missing a package ? I'm on OVH with mod_rewrite enabled...

Comment: Urls that are matching xxx.example.com (except www) because of my first rule. Using $_SERVER I can see that REQUEST_URI should correspond to your second line ! It's like this var is deleted after the redirection